# Zebra Label Printer with C#

Tags: c#, .net, printing, label

I'm having trouble printing a label using ZDesigner GK420T using C# .NET.
I converted the following string to Bytes and passed into the printer.

```
^XA 
^FO3,3^AD^FDZEBRA^FS
^XZ
```

The expected outcome was that the printer was supposed to print 'ZEBRA' but it didn't.

My C# Code:

```
StringBuilder sb; sb = new StringBuilder();
if (frmPrintJob._type != 1) 
{
    sb.AppendLine("^XA"); 
    sb.AppendLine("^FO3,3^AD^FDZEBRA^FS"); 
    sb.AppendLine("^XZ"); 
} 
int intTotalPrinted = 0; 
for (int i = 1; i <= NoOfCopies; i++) 
{ 
    if (RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(PrinterName, sb.ToString()) == true) 
        intTotalPrinted++; 
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Do I need any extra code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is totally unclear. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: i have modified the question, are you able to understand this now?

Comment: Show your code.  It didn't print.  Did it do anything?  Did it throw an exception?

Comment: @user3702654 Please add this code in your *question*, NOT here.

Comment: Do i have to convert the ZPL code into bytes before sending this to printer

Comment: Using `RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter()` the way you do should work. Make sure that the ZPL sequence is actually printing what you want it to, then use your code to send that working sequence to the printer. Maybe you are just missing some ZPL command, like `^PQ`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to clear up the following:

- are you printing an RFID label or a barcode label
- is the printer connected through USB or parallel port

For example the following snippet prints an RFID label on a Zebra printer, using the parallel port `lpt1`:

```
String strPath = "C:\\Zebra";
String zplStart = "CT~~CD,~CC^~CT~\r\n^XA\r\n^MMT\r\n^PW831\r\n^LL0599\r\n^LSO\r\n";
String zplMiddle = "^FT50,180^BY3^BCN,200,N,N,N^FD"; ///+barcode
String zplMiddle2 = "^FS\r\n^FT600,145^AAN,30,10,^FH\\^FD";///+barcode 

String zplMiddle3 = "^FS^^RS8,,800,5^RFW,H^FD";//+RFID

String splend1 = "^FS\r\n^RWH,H^FS\r\n^RR10^FS\r\n^PQ1\r\n^XZ";
string filePath = strPath + "\\Books" + ".zpl";
string Prefix="..." //Define tag ID Prefix
string Sufix =".."//Define tag ID suffix
RFID ="Prefix"+ barcode +Sufix;
StreamWriter strw = new StreamWriter(filePath);
strw.Write(zplStart + zplMiddle + barcode + zplMiddle2 + barcode+ zplMiddle3 + RFID+  splend1); // assemble the three parts of the ZPL code

string command = "copy " + filePath + " lpt1"; //prepare a string with the command to be sent to the printer
// The /c tells cmd that we want it to execute the command that follows, and then exit.
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo sinf = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command);

sinf.UseShellExecute = false;
sinf.CreateNoWindow = true;

System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process(); // new process            
p.StartInfo = sinf;//load start info into process. 
p.Start(); //start process (send file to printer)
```

The above is a sample for RFID label in your case the zpl string to feed I guess is:

```
string zpl="^XA^\r\nFO3,3^AD^FDZEBRA^FS\r\n^XZ";
```

notice I am using `\r\n` so as to  move to next line..

Comment: sorry it didnt work,
Could you please give me a zpl string that will print "ZEBRA" in GK420t

Comment: Do i need to convert this zpl string into bytes before sending it to the printer

Comment: @user3702654 Pls , consider marking my answer as correct

Answer (score 2):

The printer handles plain ASCII encoding.  Be sure to output text using `Encoding.ASCII`.  A further problem is that C# doesn't have the ability to write directly to a parallel port.  apomene shows creative use of writing to a file that is then copied to `lpt1`.  The problem is that he's not using ASCII, and is sending `UTF-16`.

I don't know what your `RawPrinterHelper` is, but is it sending text as ASCII or Unicode?

Fixing these issues will probably lead to successful printing.

I found documentation for that printer here:
http://www.servopack.de/support/zebra/ZPLII-Prog.pdf

Comment: `RawPrinterHelper` is a class which can be found on the page http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091. Since it imports the non-Unicode API functions the encoding will be taken care of inside. I have used it with great success to send ZPL to a printer attached via USB.

Comment: Try a smaller sample app that only prints your "Zebra" test.  Make sure to end with a newline (`\r\n`) after each line.